# NPM install angular@2.0.0-alpha.38 not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to `npm install angular@2.0.0-alpha.38` and it gives me this error

```
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! Invalid name: "@reactivex/rxjs"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I also have it, just tried now. seems we need to upgrade npm, see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4516 Apparently its this type of package naming that is not supported

Comment: .. solved by upgrading NPM v2.14.7 and v3 also works. Thanks @jhadesdev